# Change data between controllers with service

Tags: angularjs

When I use this it works:`

```
angular.module('app').service('DataService', function() {
   return {theme: "amelia"}
});
```

But when I use this, there is no update? Can you tell me the difference?

```
angular.module('app').service('DataService', function() {
    return {
        theme: function() {
            return {theme: "amelia"}
        }  
    };
});
```

Controller

```
$scope.settings = DataService.theme();
```

Jade

```
select.form-control(ng-model="settings.theme", ng-options="theme for theme in themes")
```

Is it possible to get the second way working? Because I will share more data then one Object!

Thank you!

Comment: This shows you one solution based on what I wrote in my answer: http://jsfiddle.net/TFDY5/2/ (and based on your fiddle)

Comment: ...and one more to show you how you could have other objects: http://jsfiddle.net/TFDY5/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first version of the code calls the function once to instantiate the service. After that, because services are singletons in angular the function isn't called again, but rather the return value (a "static" object) is accessed in *every* controller that uses the service after that.

The second version, each controller you inject the service into calls the `theme` function, which instantiates a brand new object each time. You have now effectively mitigated the fact that the service is a singleton. This is why data will not be shared with the second set of code.

If you put a break point on the function call in each case and run your code you should see the first version called once while the second version will be called many times.

**"Get It Working"...**

You can't really make it work with a function call but if you need to share multiple data objects there isn't any reason not to nest them. You could very easily do something like:

```
angular.module('app').service('DataService', function() {
   return {
      dataObjects: [
         {"type":"theme", "theme":"amelia"},
         {"type":"user", "id":123, "name":"ABC"}
      ]};
});
```

In the example I added a second object which is a user object to make shared "dataObjects" array. To find a specific object in the "dataObjects" array, you could loop till you find the correct type ("theme", for example). If necessary, you could even nest one level deeper if you needed the objects to be pristine (without the added type attribute).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

It should be theme: function().... inside your service. Replace "=" with ":".

Comment: Can you submit a jsFiddle for this problem? There may be something else which is causing the problem.